# How do I call functions from a string synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a string of function calls synchronously.
As can be seen from the example provided, the functions are called but, asynchronously.

In the example the following hanppens:
1| the function "REMOVE" is called which deletes all rows in the 4th column that has a ext length, equal to zero and therefore deleting the 2nd row in the example
2| the function "B1" is called which changes the cell value of 3rd cell from the left and the 4th from the top.
If the code would have worked synchronously cell "C5" would have a had the value "X", but in the example below the "X" is placed in cell "C4".
This because the code for running the deletion of cells takes longer than the changing of the cell value.

This is just an example of some functions that are called from the string but there are more.

I tried using setTimeOut but that did not solve the problem
`setTimeout(window[routines[i][0]](routines[i][1]),0)`

My question is, is there a way to call all the functions in the string synchronously?

```js
 function routineConverter(v){
    v = '["REMOVE",["REMOVE","ROW","-","4","HAS A LENGTH OF","=","null","0","","4"]],["B1",["X",2,3]]'
  var routines = JSON.parse('[' + v + ']');//CONVERT STRING TO ARRAY
  for ( var  i=0; i < routines.length ; i++ ){
   window[routines[i][0]](routines[i][1])
  }
 }
  
   function B1(p){ //CHANGE CELL VALUE
   $('#tbl').find('tr:eq(' + p[2] + ')').find('td:eq(' + p[1] + ')').text(p[0]);
  }
    
   //CONDITIONAL ACTIONS 
   function REMOVE(p){
  var A = p[9] //SELECTED COLUMN
  var B = p[1] //ROW,VALUE,STRING
  var C = p[3]-1 //COLUMN TO APPLY CONDITION ON
  var D = p[4] //CONDITION
  var E = p[5] //=,<,>
  var F = p[6] //ARGUMENT
  var G = p[7] //ARGUMENT VALUE
  var H = p[2] //TO BE REPLACE/APPEND/REPLACE VALUE
  var K = p[8] //REPLACE WITH VALUE
  $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + A + ')').each(function(index){
   var cellValue = $("#tbl tr:eq(" + index + ") td:eq(" + C + ")").text();
   var stringIndex = cellValue.indexOf(G);
   var tmp = false;

   switch (D) {
    case 'CONTAINS'://CONTAINS
     switch (F) {
      case 'A STRING':// USER DEFINED STRING
       if (stringIndex > -1){tmp = true;}
       break;
      case 'NUMBERS'://CONTAINS ANY NUMBERS
       if (cellValue.match(/\d+/g) != null){tmp = true;}
       break;
      case 'NUMBERS ONLY'://CONTAINS ONLY NUMBERS
       if ($.isNumeric(cellValue)){tmp = true;}
       break;
      case 'TEXT ONLY'://DOES NOT CONTAIN NUMBERS
       if (cellValue.match(/\d+/g) === null){tmp = true;}
     }
     break;
    case 'DOES NOT CONTAIN'://DOES NOT CONTAIN
     if (stringIndex == -1){tmp = true;}
     break;
    case 'HAS A LENGTH OF'://LENGTH EQUALS
     if (cellValue.length == G && E === '='){tmp = true;}
     if (cellValue.length > G && E === '&gt;'){tmp = true;}
     if (cellValue.length < G && E === '&lt;'){tmp = true;}
     break;
    case 'STARTS WITH'://STARTS WITH
     if (cellValue.substring(0, G.length) == G){tmp = true;}
     break;
    case 'ENDS WITH'://ENDS WITH
     if (cellValue.lastIndexOf(G) == cellValue.length - G.length){tmp = true;}
   }
   if (tmp === true && B === 'VALUE'){
    var X = this.innerHTML.replace(this.innerHTML, '');
    this.innerHTML = X;
   }
   if (tmp === true && B === 'ROW'){
    $(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function(){
     $(this).remove();
    });
   }
  });
 }
```

```css
table {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 95%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>F1</td>
    <td>G1</td>
    <td>H1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>F2</td>
    <td>G2</td>
    <td>H2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>E3</td>
    <td>F3</td>
    <td>G3</td>
    <td>H3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>E4</td>
    <td>F4</td>
    <td>G4</td>
    <td>H4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>B5</td>
    <td>C5</td>
    <td>D5</td>
    <td>E5</td>
    <td>F5</td>
    <td>G5</td>
    <td>H5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>B6</td>
    <td>C6</td>
    <td>D6</td>
    <td>E6</td>
    <td>F6</td>
    <td>G6</td>
    <td>H6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A7</td>
    <td>B7</td>
    <td>C7</td>
    <td>D7</td>
    <td>E7</td>
    <td>F7</td>
    <td>G7</td>
    <td>H7</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A8</td>
    <td>B8</td>
    <td>C8</td>
    <td>D8</td>
    <td>E8</td>
    <td>F8</td>
    <td>G8</td>
    <td>H8</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A9</td>
    <td>B9</td>
    <td>C9</td>
    <td>D9</td>
    <td>E9</td>
    <td>F9</td>
    <td>G9</td>
    <td>H9</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A10</td>
    <td>B10</td>
    <td>C10</td>
    <td>D10</td>
    <td>E10</td>
    <td>F10</td>
    <td>G10</td>
    <td>H10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A11</td>
    <td>B11</td>
    <td>C11</td>
    <td>D11</td>
    <td>E11</td>
    <td>F11</td>
    <td>G11</td>
    <td>H11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
 <button type="button" onclick="routineConverter()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Your functions are already called synchronously, the only function call that is called async is the `remove()` call because it is inside the `fadeOut()` callback.

Comment: That did solve the problem. Thanks @Patrick Evans.